# vectorized shuffling per row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, permutation

I want to shuffle the columns of a pandas data frame.
However, the default method (sample) shuffles all the columns in the same way.

How can I efficiently shuffle the columns of each row differently?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':[1,4,7],'bar':[2,5,8],'baz':[3,6,9],})
display(df)
df.sample(frac=1, axis=1)
```

Certainly, an `apply` based solution would work - but this would not be vectorized and thus slow.

[image]

Is there a fast (and ideally vectorized) way to sample differently for each row?

Comment: If you shuffle each row independently, then that would break the index alignment along the columns axis, so the column names are essentially of no use anymore. Is this what you want?

Comment: yes. This is exactly what I want.

Comment: Check my answer. I think it is doing exactly as per your need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try with `np.random.rand` and `argsort` to generate shuffled indices

```
i = np.random.rand(*df.shape).argsort(1)
df.values[:] = np.take_along_axis(df.to_numpy(), i, axis=1)
```

---

```
print(df)

   foo  bar  baz
0    3    1    2
1    4    5    6
2    7    9    8
```

Comment: Ah this will be much faster than my answer as it uses argsort. Awesome answer.

Comment: awesome! seems to be the fastest one so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution:

```
def shuffle_columns_per_row(df):
    arr = df.values
    x, y = arr.shape
    rows = np.indices((x,y))[0]
    cols = [np.random.permutation(y) for _ in range(x)]
    return pd.DataFrame(arr[rows, cols], columns=df.columns)

| foo | bar | baz |
|-----|-----|-----|
| 3   | 2   | 1   |
| 5   | 6   | 4   |
| 9   | 7   | 8   |
```

Comment: This correctly gives a random permutation for each row. Is there however also a faster implementation available?

Comment: This will be relatively faster as we are not doing permutation of values, we are doing permutation of indices only.

Answer (score 0):

A quick check gives the benchmark:

```py
%%timeit
df.sample(frac=1, axis=1) 
# 1000 loops, best of 5: 288 µs per loop
```

With `apply`, as you said, we get:

```py
%%timeit
idx = np.random.choice([0, 1, 2], size=(3,), replace=False)
df.apply(lambda x: x.iloc[idx], axis=1)
# 1000 loops, best of 5: 1.47 ms per loop -> ~3700 times slower
```

We could rather use `iloc`:

```py
%%timeit
idx = np.random.choice([0, 1, 2], size=(3,), replace=False)
df.iloc[:, idx]
# 1000 loops, best of 5: 398 µs per loop -> ~1.4 times slower
```

If you could live with a roughly 1.4 times decrease in speed, I think the `iloc` version would work.

Comment: Performance-wise this looks great. But when calculating it the columns are still all shuffled in the same way (at least for this 3 column example).

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "the same way"? Do you want to shuffle the columns themselves, or the values of the columns without changing the column name?